# How can I reuse a created column in spark sql (databricks)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to create a new_var column using "end as", and then use it in a new case statement and save it as new_var_2, is this possible in databricks SQL?

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)],['id','value'])
df.registerTempTable('sql_df')
df.show()

+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    1|
|  2|    2|
|  3|    3|
+---+-----+


%sql
Select * ,
Case 
      when a.id = 1 then  "A"
      when a.id = 2 then "B"
      end as new_var,
      Case 
      when new_var  = "B" then "U"
      end as new_var_2
   
  from sql_df as a;

"Expected base"
    +---+-----+-------+---------+
    | id|value|new_var|new_var_2|
    +---+-----+-------+---------+
    |  1|    1|      A|     null|
    |  2|    2|      B|        U|
    |  3|    3|   null|     null|
    +---+-----+-------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery:

```
Select * ,
Case 
      when new_var  = "B" then "U"
      end as new_var_2
from (
select *,
Case 
      when a.id = 1 then  "A"
      when a.id = 2 then "B"
      end as new_var   
from sql_df as a
);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! but is there another way?

Comment: can't think of another way. what's wrong with this?

Comment: I'm transcribing a huge code from sas to databricks, if I have to subselect for every variable that I create to read it next, then the code will get unnecessarily large and confusing to understand. I would like a simpler way without having to keep creating several bases.

Comment: you should consider using the dataframe api, where you can use withColumn to simply all of these

Answer (score 0):

You can have two case statement on id .
1 - for new_var
2 - fro new_var-2

ie.

```
Select * ,
Case 
      when a.id = 1 then  "A"
      when a.id = 2 then "B"
      end as new_var,
   Case 
      when a.id = 2  then "U"
      end as new_var_2
   
  from sql_df as a;
```

Comment: The code above is just an example, the challenge is to read a created variable and then read it in the same query.